# Rational Matrix Invertible mod p when Restricted to the Integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, orthogonality, integers

I'm interested in finding a basis for $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ with the following properties: Given an integer vector $v,$ we can find a collection of rational vectors $v_{j}$, $2\leq j\leq n$, such that $\{v,v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ by applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure to, say, $\{v,e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$, where $e_{i}$ are the standard unit vectors. Note that we can't suppose that these are orthonormal, since (1) this usually requires square roots, which may not belong to $\mathbb{Q},$ and (2) $\|v\|$ may not be $1.$ I would like the additional property that if $V$ is the matrix with $v,v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}$ as its columns, that if $x$ and $y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ such that $Vx,Vy\in\mathbb{Z}^{n},$ and $Vx\equiv Vy\pmod{p\mathbb{Z}^{n}}$ for an odd prime $p,$ then $x\equiv y\,\pmod{p\mathbb{Z}^{n}}$. How might we characterize this condition equivalently? How do I enforce it in the construction of $v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}$? Is it always possible?

Note that if $V\in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}),$ then $V$ encodes a linear map $\mathbb{Q}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}^{n},$ so we may consider $A\subset\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ where $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}:Vx\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}\},$ and the restriction of $V$ to $A$, $V|_{A}:A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{n}.$ Then the condition above is equivalent to $V|_{A}$ being invertible mod $p$. If possible, I would like to characterize this in terms of properties of $V$, but I'm not there yet.

My guess is that if $\mathrm{det}(V)=a/b$ is in reduced form, that $V|_{A}$ is invertible mod $p$ if and only if $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p},$ but I don't know how to prove this. If there were a simpler condition than this, that would be even better.

Comment: The title does not sound reasonable. Maybe "Gram-Schmidt" is a better keyword.

Comment: The main question here is how to characterize $Vx\equiv Vy\pmod{p\mathbb{Z}^{n}}\Rightarrow x\equiv y\pmod{p\mathbb{Z}^{n}}$; the part about Gram-Schmidt is meant to provide context for the matrices I'm considering.

Comment: Anyway, the rational matrix invertible (take size $1$ for simplicity), say $A=(1/2)$ when restricted to integers, is not clear to me. To what integer do you restrict?

Comment: You'd have to restrict to $2\mathbb{Z}$ in this case, so that $(1/2)x\in\mathbb{Z}$ for any $x$ in consideration.